# Click event defined in the jquery ready on new element

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically Adding Elements and trying to use the selectors .click event Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384588/dynamically-adding-elements-and-trying-to-use-the-selectors-click-event-jquery)

```
$(function(){
  $('a.bar').click(function(){
    // do something
  });

  $('a.foo').click(function(){
    $('#toto').append('<a class="bar">bar</a>');
  });
});


 <a class="foo">foo</a>
 <div id="toto"></div>
```

How to automatically attach the click event defined in the JQuery ready for a dom element that was added by an other event (for instance by clicking on `a.foo` for `a.bar`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the delegated event technique.. See below using `.on`

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.bar', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Should the $(document) be outside the 'ready'?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an `init()` function where you set all the triggers and call it after the DOM modification. E.g.:

```
$(function() {
  init();

  $('a.foo').click(function(){
    $('#toto').append('<a class="bar">bar</a>');
    init();
  });
});

function init() {
  $('a.bar').click(function(){
    // do something
  });
}
```

Comment: That's what i want to avoid

Comment: The first click will be fine.. but the next clicks would bind the handler for all `.bar` which already has a handler

Comment: Vega: True, but you could check it using the `$('a.bar').data('events')` or by unbinding the `click` event before. My answer is just a hint, not the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.foo').click(function(){
    $('<a class="bar">bar</a>').appendTo('#toto');
  });

  $('#toto').delegate('.bar', 'click', function(a){
    $('.foo').toggle();    
  });
});
```

Use delegate.