# .remove() not working properly with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery

i have a link that when clicked it loads an ajax content on a div:

html:

```
<div class="noticiaAberta"></div>
```

ajax function:

```
$('#feedbackNoticia a').click(function(){
    $.post('teste.php', function(data){
        $('#noticiasBox .descricao').fadeOut(200);
        $('#noticiasBox .noticiaAberta').delay(200).fadeIn(200).html(data);
    })
});
```

and this is the ajax file:

```
<div class="ajax">
    <a class="close"></a>
    <img src="assets/images/temp/noticia-clicada.jpg" alt="">
    <h1>teste adf asdf laskdfjl aksdjfl kasjdflk jasdlfk jasldkf jasd asdfk lahsdfkl jhasdkfj hasdfkhj</h1>
    <div class="pNoticias">
        <p>teste</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.ajax .close').click(function(){
        $('.ajax').remove();
    })
</script>
```

the ajax is working, but the remove function isnt working properly, when i click it only remove the `.close` link

does someone knows what is it?

Comment: Well, I don't know what your css is like, but the `.close` element is empty, so are you sure you are clicking it and not some other element instead? Also, put `console.log( $(this) )` inside your `.ajax .close` click event to see what the clicked element was, or if it was found at all.

Answer (score 2):

Change the Javascript for something like:

```
$(document).on('click','.ajax .close', function(){
    $('.ajax').remove();
})
```

That way, you'll be sure that any dynamically created element that matches the specified selector will have the handler attached.

Comment: I guess that `$(this).closest(".ajax")` would be better

Comment: i use this
`$('.ajax .close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".ajax")
})`
but didnt work ://
i also tryed the `$(document).on...` and had the same issue

Comment: So my bet is that @Joonas is right. It seems that the link with the class `close` does not have width and height, unless you define it in your css. Are you sure you are clicking on the link?

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be defined in the JQuery ready and you should use a delegate in order to bind automatically all the new element that cames from the Ajax result.

```
  $(function(){
     $(document).delegate('.ajax, .close', 'click', function(){
         $('.ajax').remove();    
     });
  });
```

See this post for more info: [Dynamically Adding Elements and trying to use the selectors .click event Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384588/dynamically-adding-elements-and-trying-to-use-the-selectors-click-event-jquery)

http://jsfiddle.net/fTk6t/

Comment: `delegate` is outdated. Use `on`

Comment: i also tried the .on, but didnt work too. i'll read this post.

Comment: i added the script on the ajax loaded .php file

Comment: move it to the page that will make the ajax call and be sure to include your function as I did, in the JQuery ready

Comment: now i put it where the ajax is called:
`$('#feedbackNoticia a').click(function(){
    $.post('teste.php', function(data){
     $('#noticiasBox .descricao').fadeOut(200);
     $('#noticiasBox .noticiaAberta').delay(200).fadeIn(200).html(data);
    })
   });
   $(document).on('.ajax .close', 'click', function(){
          $('.ajax').remove();    
      });`
but know it dont work at all. i think i cant call where i call the ajax because the content is being added dynamically and it wont work the function for the loaded content, am i right?

Comment: See my edit, can you add this '$(function(){ your code... });'

Comment: its already inside a `$(function(){..})` i just put a part of the code here

Comment: yes, its like that u show on jsfiddle, but when the content is being loaded, somehow it works differently. in this example using .delegate only the .close link is being removed, the other content continues displeyed

Answer (score 0):

i just solved the problem. the problem was that the `.ajax` div was without height, i put a `float:left` and solved the problem -.-

thanks to all!